# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required Error

Tags: asp.net

This code gives me error again and again. I tried many things but i am unable to do please help me.

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
       mail.From = new MailAddress("hello@gmail.com");
       mail.To.Add("hello@gmail.com");
       mail.Subject = "Hello World";
       mail.Body = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
       mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


      using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
      {
         smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hello@gmail.com", "hello");
         smtp.EnableSsl = true;
         smtp.Send(mail);
      }
}

WEB.CONFIG
  <system.net>
       <mailSettings>

           <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="unknownuser6601@gmail.com">
           <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="unknownuser6601@gmail.com" password="ASADsohaib" />
           </smtp>

       </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```